# How do you say "tape it" as in, "taping a package"?

Tags: translation

Google translate says "tape" is 胶带, and "tape it" is 用胶带.

But to me, that's just saying "use tape".

Is there a verb for the act of taping something?

For example, how would you say "could you tape that package?"
or "can you tape that shut?"

Comment: "Could you tape that package" 你能 **用胶带捆好** (or 用胶带封上) 那个包裹吗? It seems we don't have a concise expression in Chinese and have to say something like "could you **tie/seal** the package **with tape**?"

Comment: also answered by dictionaries e。g。iciba：用带子捆扎，用带子系紧， 以带子绑起 <美>缠绷带于，用绷带包扎  （anyhow somewhat of an Americanism？）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

用胶带捆 (literally: bind with tape) seems a good translation.
Ancient Chinese has many similar verbs directly from nouns, but there are much fewer, if not none, in Modern Chinese. So there are some cases that a single English word must be translated into a long phrase in Chinese.

Answer (score 6):

To communicate the same generic sense as the English verb to tape, try 貼 (simplified: 贴), pinyin: tie1

Examples:

t: 可以幫我把它貼起來嗎?

s: 可以帮我把它贴起来吗?

e: Can you help me tape it up?

- appropriate for situations such as sealing a package like a present for someone
- "tape that shut"

t: 我貼好了

s: 我贴好了

e: I finished taping

- for example after applying duct tape to repair a hole in an air duct, you can say this

Machine translation such as Google is still somewhat hit-and-miss, I'm sure you have come across [translation fails](http://www.boredpanda.com/funny-chinese-translation-fails/) that make you wonder *Did they use Google Translate?*. Better to use machine translation as a last resort when no native language speaker is available.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just say'用胶带包起来' or '用胶带包上'? That's what my Chinese wife would say every time we went through the hussle of sending a package to China.